# Comparing each adjacent values of the list

Tags: python-3.x

I'm working on lists in Python 3. What am I trying to do is;
I have 2 lists one of them have custom numbers,
other one is empty.
The aim of the code is checking if 1st list's value is bigger than previous value and if it is bigger than previous element, append it to the 2nd list.

I have to use basic pythonic syntax. I cannot use any libraries etc.

```py
list1=[5,9,3,2,7,11]
list2 = []
for i in range(len(list1)):
    if list1[i] < list1[i+1]:
        list2.append(list1[i+1])
print (list2)
```

If I run whole block of code I got;

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-209-8d49a68543e3>", line 4, in <module>
    if list1[i] < list1[i+1]:

IndexError: list index out of range
```

but when I run just `list2` I get what am I expecting which is
`[9,7,11]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't go all the way up to `len(list1) - 1` for the value of `i` and expect `i+1` to be an index in the list. `list[len(list1)]` is outside the list.

If you need `i+1` in the loop, the loop can only go till all possible valid values of `i+1` which happens to be `len(list1) - 2`. To get that you need to tweak the `range` a bit

```
list1=[5,9,3,2,7,11]
list2 = []
for i in range(len(list1) - 1): # iterate until penultimate index
    if list1[i] < list1[i+1]:
        list2.append(list1[i+1])
print (list2)
```

Comment: Thank you so much. It works and I also understood thanks to your comment.

Answer (score 0):

could you use the following instead of ranges?  Also uses f strings to print list2

```
for idx, number in enumerate(list1[:-1]):
    if number > list1[idx + 1]:
         list2.append(list1[idx + 1])
print(f'{list2 = }')
```